# Improving performance when querying tables by datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, performance, datetime

I made an application which register users when signing in and signing out from another application. The application basically logs the users ID, device, IP, and sign in as a timestamp.

| id | user | device | ip | signed_in | signed_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 | ChromeOS | 174.134.24.35 | 2020-05-01 09:32:01 | 2020-05-01 18:32:01 |
| 2 | 39 | ChromeOS | 174.134.24.35 | 2020-05-01 09:32:01 | 2020-05-01 18:32:01 |

I'll save the details and just say the purpose of this app is to then sum the time an user spends in another application, each month.

The SQL query to get all the users for a month is relatively simple:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id = 38 
  AND signed_in >= 2020-05-01 00:00:00
  AND signed_out < 2020-06-01 00:00:00
```

While initially there wasn't any problem, I have been reported a *massive slowdown* to generate the sum, which has been grown as more people is using the web services. After some meddling, the query slows downs massively because of the timestamps, as a full sweep must be done.

### Possible solution

I haven't found any solutions for this performance problems, except for one: adding columns for year and month combination, index them, and use them with the query.

| id | user | device | ip | year | month | signed_in | signed_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 | ChromeOS | 174.134.24.35 | 2020 | 5 | 2020-05-01 09:32:01 | 2020-05-01 18:32:01 |
| 2 | 39 | ChromeOS | 174.134.24.35 | 2020 | 5 | 2020-05-01 09:32:01 | 2020-05-01 18:32:01 |

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id = 38 
  AND year = 2020
  AND month = 5
```

This may be a *good way* to not tie a solution to a single database engine (I'm considering MySQL and PostgreSQL). This approach seems unavoidable considering the larger the database it gets, the longer the database sweeps the table, and indexes can help with dealing thousands of records generated by each month.

Apart from this solution, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What index did you create with your original columns? My guess is you had the date time as the first column, meaning you had to read all of the index that met the date range (including ones that didn’t match on the `id` Filter)

Comment: The sum of what?  Is the issue with the query in your question or some other query?

Answer (score 1):

Your "Possible Solution" would work well with

```
INDEX(id, year, month)
```

with the columns in any order.  If you have `ID...AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY(id)` then an even better solution would be

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, year, month)
```

(That loses the uniqueness check on `ID` by itself; but that is probably not important.  It speeds up your query.)

The drawback is that the query only works for testing for a month, not a week, etc.

I'm confused.  What is `id`?  The table is named `users`, yet you have both `id` and `user` columns.  Maybe the table should be called `logins` and the query should have `WHERE user=39 AND ...`??  If so, I will need to rethink my Answer.

Furthermore, you say "users ID" but show two columns??

Comment: The primary key is for checking a session. For example, if someone says "I was logged in the whole day!", we can check that particular login. That happens a lot, so there is no slowdown when getting the row `14568`.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your query is selecting at most 1% of the rows of the table. That's needed for an index to be effective.

Then, I would slightly rephrase your query as:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id = 38 
  AND signed_in between '2020-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-05-30 23:59:59'
  AND signed_out < '2020-05-30 23:59:59'
```

Your query rephrased this way can effectively access rows by `id` and `signed_in` using the index:

```
create index ix1 on users (id, signed_in, signed_out);
```

Notice I also added `signed_out` to the index, for coverage puporses and to avoid double hit on the indexes.

Also, I assumed the columns `signed_in` and `signed_out` are not `VARCHAR` but `DATETIME`.

Comment: I can't get around this approach. Considering a normal Index using some sort of BTree, I assume than an index by year and month would be better and indexing the whole datetime.

Comment: @DarkGhostHunter An index by year and month will be as efficient as the one in this answer. They will both scan the exact same rows. The benefit of this solution is that you don't need redundancy (year, month) in your table.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE id = 38 AND
      signed_in >= '2020-05-01' AND
      signed_out < '2020-05-31'
```

Although I'm guessing that you *really* want:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE id = 38 AND
      signed_in >= '2020-05-01' AND
      signed_out < '2020-06-01'
```

This has users who signed in only during the month of May.  I would expect that at index on either `users(id, signed_in)` or `users(id, signed_out)` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't solves the problem of performance.

Comment: @DarkGhostHunter . . . Did you try the indexes?